# Approximate the root using Newton's method - Convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Let $f(x)=x^3-1$. To approximate the root $x^{\star}=1$, we consider the sequence $(x_n)$ that we get if we apply Newton's method with $x_0>0$. Show that the sequence converges to $1$.

I have done the following:

I used $x_0=0,5$ and applied the method and in that way we see that the sequence converges to $1$.

Is that correct?

Now I think that we could also do the following:

From Newton's method we get $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^3-1}{3x_n^2}=\frac{2x_n^3+1}{3x_n^2}$ and we have to show that this sequence converges to $1$, or not?

Comment: I don't get the last equality? Typo?

Comment: Oh yes, I corrected it @Dude

Comment: Are both ways correct? Or can we only apply one of them for that question? Or  are both false? @Dude

Comment: Yes you need to prove that the last sequence you wrote goes to $1$

Comment: Ok! I will try that! Is the first way I described also correct? @Dude

Comment: Mmh no, how do you see that it converges to $1$? By looking at the first few terms? This does not constitute a proof

Comment: Ok.. So for the second way. Let $\ell$ be the limit, then we get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2x_n^3+1}{3x_n^2} \Rightarrow \ell=\frac{2\ell^3+1}{3\ell^2} \Rightarrow 3\ell^3=2\ell^3+1 \Rightarrow \ell^3=1 $$ Is that correct so far? @Dude

Comment: But now we have the same problem as the original one, or not? @Dude

Comment: Yes it is correct! Now it remains to show that the sequence actually converges.

Comment: But can we just say here that $\ell=1$ ? Isn't this equation equivalent to $f(x)=0$ (the original one) ? To prove that it converges do we apply the ratio test? @Dude

Comment: The initial equation does give you at once the solution $x=1$, so I wonder why you are surprised that the limit goes to $1$ :). Why the ratio test? You aren't dealing with a series.

Comment: But how do we show then that the sequence actually converges? @Dude

Comment: Does the sequence converges if we know that the function $f(x)$ has a root? @Dude

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x_0 > 1$, show that the sequence is decreasing.  If $0 < x_0 < 1$, show that $x_1 > 1$.

Comment: So we consider $x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n^3+1}{3x_n^2}$. How c=do we see that the sequence is decreasing if $x_0>1$ ? .

Comment: Simplify $x - \frac{2 x^3+1}{3 x^2}$ and $\frac{2 x^3+1}{3 x^2} - 1$.

Comment: How did you get that? I got stuck right now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you didn't quite understand the other answer, so let me elaborate on that.
We have $$x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n^3+1}{3x_n^2} < x_n \rightarrow1< x_n^3\rightarrow x_n>1$$Now assuming that we have proven that $x_n > 1$ for all $n\ge n_0$, it follows that $x_n$ is decreasing from $n_0$; your sequence being bounded below by $1$ is thus convergent.

To show that $x_n>1$ we proceed by induction as follows: if $x_0 > 1$ we may assume $n_0 = 0$. Now $$x_{n+1}=\frac{2x_n^3+1}{3x_n^2} > 1\rightarrow2x_n^3-3x_n^2+1>0$$Put $t=x_n$. So $2t^3-3t^2+1>0\leftrightarrow2t^2(t-1)>(t-1)(t+1)$. Since $t>1$ by our induction hypotesis we may divide by $(t-1)$, and get $2t^2-t-1>0$ which is again true for $t>1$ as you can check.

If $x_0 < 1$ then we may assume $n_0=1$, for $x_1 = \frac{2x_0^3+1}{3x_
0^2}>1 \leftrightarrow2x_0^3-3x_0^2+1>0$. As above $2x_0^2(x_0-1)>(x_0-1)(x_0+1)$ and dividing by $x_0-1$ which is *negative*, we obtain $2x_0^2-x_0-1<0$ which is again satisfied as you can check.

Comment: So first we consider the case $x_0>1$. At the base case we have for $n=0$ that $x_1=\frac{2}{3}x_0+\frac{1}{3x_0^2}>1$. At the inuctive hypothesis we assume that it holds for $n=k$, i.e. $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{x_k^3-1}{3x_k^2}>1 \Rightarrow 2x_k^3-3x_k^2+1>0$. At the inductive step we want to show that it holds for $n=k+1$, i.e.  that $x_{k+2}=x_{k+1}-\frac{x_{k+1}^3-1}{3x_{k+1}^2}>1$. I haven't really understood how we could show that using the inductive hypothesis. Could you explain that further to me?

Comment: We assume that $x_k > 1$ holds and we want to prove that $x_{k+1} > 1$ holds again. To prove that I used the fact that $t>1$, which basically is $x_k>1$. I hope it is clear :)

Comment: So we want to show that $x_{k+1}>1$ which is equivalent to $2x_k^3-3x_k^2+1>0$ knwoing that $x_k>1$, right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Ok! I have also an other question.. Why do we take at the case $x_0>1$ that $n_0=0$ and at the case $x_0<1$ that $n_0=1$ ?

Comment: If you read above you see that I defined $n_0$ to be the first index for which $x_n>1$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Since in the case $x_0>1$ we have proved that $0$ is the first index, then $n_0=0$. In the other case $x_0<1$ but $x_1>1$ as is proved, so the first index is $1$.

Comment: I got it now! Thank you very much!! :-)